# Using ToList() on Enumerable LINQ query results for large data sets - Efficiency Issue?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, .net-4.0, type-conversion

I've been making a lot of use of LINQ queries in the application I'm currently writing, and one of the situations that I keep running into is having to convert the LINQ query results into lists for further processing (I have my reasons for wanting lists).

I'd like to have a better understanding of what happens in this list conversion in case there are inefficiencies since I've used it repeatedly now.  So, given I execute a line line like this:

```
var matches = (from x in list1 join y in list2 on x equals y select x).ToList();
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any overhead here aside from the creation of a new list and its population with references to the elements in the Enumerable returned from the query?
2. Would you consider this inefficient?
3. Is there a way to get the LINQ query to directly generate a list to avoid the need for a conversion in this circumstance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it creates a copy of the data. That *could* be inefficient - but it depends on what's going on. If you *need* a `List<T>` at the end, `List<T>` is usually going to be close to as efficient as you'll get. The one exception to that is if you're going to *just* do a conversion and the source is already a list - then using `ConvertAll` will be more efficient, as it can create the backing array of the right size to start with.

If you *only* need to stream the data - e.g. you're just going to do a `foreach` on it, and taking actions which don't affect the original data sources - then calling `ToList` is definitely a potential source of inefficiency. It will force the whole of `list1` to be evaluated - and if that's a lazily-evaluated sequence (e.g. "the first 1,000,000 values from a random number generator") then that's not good. Note that as you're doing a join, `list2` will be evaluated *anyway* as soon as you try to pull the first value from the sequence (whether that's in order to populate a list or not).

You might want to read my [Edulinq post on `ToList`](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist/) to see what's going on - at least in one possible implementation - in the background.

Comment: This might sound trivial, but what data is copied in `ToList` call?

Comment: So, you're saying that until I run a line that uses the first element of matches (like a foreach or matches[0]), the query isn't actually evaluated, right?

Comment: @jimmy_keen: The values in the sequence. In this case, the `x` values.

Comment: @w00te: Not if you don't include `ToList`, that's right - but the `ToList` forces immediate evaluation. I suggest you read Edulinq from the start :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Already started looking at it :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: Fixed, thanks. (I moved my blog a while ago.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no any other overhed except those ones already mantioned by you.
2. I would say yes, but it depends on concrete application scenario. By the way, *in general* it's better to avoid additional calls. (I think this is obvious).
3. I'm afraid not. The `LINQ query` return *a sequence* of data, that *could be* an infinit sequence potentially. Converting to `List<T>` you make it finit, with also a possibility of index access, which is not possible to have in *sequence* or *stream*.

Suggession: avoid situation where you need the `List<T>`. If, by the way, you need it, push inside as less data as you you need in the current moment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate the infinite sequence example.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said, if the initial two lists that you're joining were already quite large, creating a third (creating an "intersection" of the two) could cause out of memory errors.  If you just iterate the result of the LINQ statement, you'll reduce the memory usage dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.ToList(source)` is essentially just a call to `new List(source)`.

This constructor will test whether source is an `ICollection<T>`, and if it is allocate an array of the appropriate size. In other cases, i.e. most cases where the source is a LINQ query, it will allocate an array with the default initial capacity (four items) and grow it by doubling the capacity as needed. Each time the capacity doubles, a new array is allocated and the old one is copied over into the new one.

This may introduce some overhead in cases where your list wil have a lot of items (we're probably talking thousands at least). The overhead can be significant as soon as the list grows over 85 KB, as it is then allocated on the Large Object Heap, which is not compacted and may suffer from memory fragmentation. Note that I'm refering to the array in the list. If `T` is a reference type, that array contains only references, not the actual objects. Those objects then don't count for the 85 KB limitation.

You could remove some of this overhead if you can accurately estimate the size of your sequence (where it is better to overestimate a little bit than it is to underestimate a little bit). For example, if you are only running a `.Select()` operator on something that implements `ICollection<T>`, you know the size of the output list.

In such cases, this extension method would reduce this overhead:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int initialCapacity)
{
    // parameter validation ommited for brevity

    var result = new List<T>(initialCapacity);

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In some cases, the list you create is just going to replace a list that was already there, e.g. from a previous run. In those cases, you can avoid quite a few memory allocations if you reuse the old list. That would only work if you don't have concurrent access to that old list though, and I wouldn't do it if new lists will typically be significantly smaller than old lists. If that's the case, you can use this extension method:

```
public static void CopyToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, List<T> destination)
{
    // parameter validation ommited for brevity

    destination.Clear();

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        destination.Add(item);
    }
}
```

This being said, would I consider `.ToList()` being inefficient? No, if you have the memory, and you're going to use the list repeatedly, either for random indexing into it a lot, or iterating over it multiple times.

Now back to your specific example:

```
var matches = (from x in list1 join y in list2 on x equals y select x).ToList();
```

It *may* be more efficient to do this in some other way, for example:

```
var matches = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

which would yield the same results if list1 and list2 don't contain duplicates, and is very efficient if list2 is small.

The only way to really know though, as usual, is to measure using typical workloads.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most of the overhead happens before the list creation like the connection to db, getting the data to
   an adapter, for the var type the .NET need to decide it's data type/structure...
2. The efficiency is very relative term. For a programmer who doesn't strong in SQL is efficient, 
   faster developing (relatively to old ADO) the overheads detailed in 1.
3. On the other hand LINQ can call procedures from the db itself, which already faster.
   I suggest you to to the next test:

   - Run your program on maximal amount of data and measure the time.
   - Use some db procedure to export the data to file (like XML, CSV,....) and try to build your list
     from that file and measure the time.
     Then you can see if the difference is significant.
     But the second ways is less efficient for the programmer, but can reduce the run time.

Comment: There is no runtime overhead associated with using `var`. The type resolution happens during compilation.

Comment: And it still need to be resolved JIT.  I gave this example to show that program accessing to DB generally takes more time than straight from the db.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about the database call. If a database call is involved, whatever `.ToList()` does will be insignificant. But you are absolutely wrong about `var` needing to be resolved at JIT compilation time. The JIT sees the actual type, it has been resolved by the C# compiler.